# ¿Cómo compartir una imagen a través de un ImageView?

Tags: java, android, webservice

Tengo esta enorme dudad y no logro aclararla, estoy usando `Webservice` donde en mi app alimento la información que necesito, en este caso una foto, me lo muestra en la aplicación ahora lo que quiero es compartir esa imagen a alguna red social, pero no he encontrado alguna referencia.
Aquí esta la instrucción del `bundle`:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_producto);
    foto =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgFotoProducto);
    share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_compartir);

}
```

Después de esto tengo el Response de mi webservice

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    progreso.hide();
    PRODUCTO producto = new PRODUCTO();
    JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("producto");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    try {
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(0);
            producto.setDATO(jsonObject.optString("foto"));
            producto.setESTATUS(jsonObject.optString("estatus"));

    }catch (JSONException E){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+E,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
foto.setImageBitmap(producto.getFOTOGRAFIA());
```

Ahora tengo el botón con su `setOnclickListener`

> ¿Como puedo ad-apartarla para poder compartir esa imagen que esta en
>   la ImageView?

Comment: ¿Lo que obtienes de jsonObject.optString("foto") es una url de una imagen o que es lo que se almacena ahí?

Comment: Lo que agrego ahí es un dato de tipo LongBlob, y cuando pasas por el archivo  tiene esta variable $jsArray["foto"]=base64_encode($dato["FOTOGRAFIA"]);

Comment: Puedes probar con esto: [Share An Image Without Saving](https://www.logicchip.com/share-image-without-saving/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto, una vez que agregaste  o definiste la imagen a tu ImageView, puedes obtener el Bitmap de esta imagen mediante el método `getDrawingCache()`.

Procedes a salvarla en disco, este punto es muy importante para poder anexarla y enviarla mediante un `Intent` :

```
    Bitmap bitmap = foto.getDrawingCache();
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/imagen.jpg");
    try {
        cachePath.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Error enviando imagen " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Estupendo, este era la pieza del rompecabezas que me faltaba para hacer el proceso.

Comment: Listo, solucionado @Jorgesys